# How to determine why a static external IP address changed in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I noticed that a static external IP address changed in GCP in our project.  I'm trying to determine why and when, and i'm not finding any useful information in the google console.

Is there any way to view history of a external IP?  Creation date, deletion date, etc?

Has anyone heard or experienced Google changing a static external IP address?  If so, what were the circumstances?

Edit:

To clarify, yes this is a reserved static ip address.  I'm thinking that some piece of automation deleted it and re-created it at some point, hence the question about any history that google keeps around these addresses.  We are just having trouble tracking down what happened, so that we can ensure it doesn't happen again.

The only other possibility i can think of is a bug on google's side, hence the question about anyone hearing about this happening.

It had sat unused for a while, which would allow the possibility of either of those things.

Comment: If your question was correct, infrastructure on Google Cloud would collapse globally. Reserved Static IP addresses do not change. Therefore, if your address changed, then you have configured something incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Cloud, there are two lifetimes for external public IP addresses: reserved and ephemeral. There are also two types: global and regional.

A reserved IP address does not change. These addresses are allocated to your project and can be moved between resources.

An ephemeral IP address is assigned to a resource and does not persist beyond the life of the resource. This means that when the resource stops or is deleted, the ephemeral address is released back to a common pool of available addresses. When a resource is restarted, sometimes the same address is assigned, but that is not predictable.

Common reasons for an IP address to change is that you stopped and then restarted a Compute resource.

[Ephemeral and static IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses#ephemeral_and_static_ip_addresses)

If you do not want the external public IP address to change, reserve the address.

[Reserving a static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this is a static IP address.

Comment: @tom - is it a **reserved** IP address? Reserved addresses do not change. Double-check your settings.